# Line segmentation in handwritten text

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I'm developing a simple script for extracting features of each of the lines of a image that contains handwritten text.

After thresholding the image I add to the Numpy matrix a complete white row and complete black row (first two rows).
I want to calculate pairwise the cosine similarity of the white row and each of the  the rows of the image matrix, I want to do the same with the black row. I want to use the cosine similarity (black row and white row) as input feature in order to train a Knn with scikit learn.

The code:

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)

ret2,t = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
white=np.full((t.shape[1]), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
black=np.full((t.shape[1]), 1,   dtype=np.uint8)
tn=np.vstack((white,np.vstack((black,t))))

tn[tn==0]=1 #Set all 0 values to 1

cdist=distance.cdist(tn, tn, 'cosine')
```

The problem is cdist is all 0. I don't get the expected values. What am I missing?

Are there any other techniques to consider when splitting an image with text into lines?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give sample images and describe the problem with a little more detail? its difficult to understand what you get after thresholding and why you need white and black rows.

Comment: I want to measure the cosine similarity of each one of the image rows in relation to the reference white line and the reference black line. I want to know how similar the different rows of the image are related to black line and the white line.